# Is there a way to precisely quantify entanglement in general?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Entanglement is among the most remarkable features of quantum mechanics. It is pointed out by many as the responsible for breaking Bell inequalities and numerous other surprising aspects of quantum theory. My issue is that I do not understand how to quantify entanglement in general quantum systems.

I know that the [Entanglement Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_of_entanglement) is a very good quantifier for pure states. However, most physical states are not pure. For mixed states in bipartite two-level systems, I know that the [Negativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negativity_(quantum_mechanics)) (or Concurrence) are good entanglement quantifiers and are equivalent, making it seem that there is a "unique" way of quantifying entanglement in these systems.

My question is: What quantifiers can be used for mixed states in more general setups with multipartite systems and general Hilbert spaces? Is there a "unique", or best way of quantifying entanglement in these setups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining whether or not a given mixed state was proven to be an NP-hard problem by [Gurvits](https://doi.org/10.1145/780542.780545). Given that, it's quite challenging to have an easy formula for quantifying entanglement, even for bipartite systems! It is worth recalling that nonzero negativity is only a sufficient condition for bipartite entanglement in most dimensions: there are entangled states with zero negativity.

In general, there are infinitely many witnesses of entanglement, each of which gives a sufficient condition for the existence of entanglement; to prove entanglement/separability, one has to check many different witnesses. So, in that sense, there is neither a unique nor a best way of quantifying entanglement in general. There may be specific purposes for which specific types of entanglement are useful and so that can always inform your choice of an entanglement quantifier.